# Segmentation Fault when starting google-chrome-stable on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: amazon-ec2, segmentation-fault, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-18.04

Just started experiencing crashes when trying to start google-chrome-stable with Xvfb via the CLI. Specifically the AWS EC2 AMI "Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS, amd64 bionic image build on 2018-09-12"

Chrome has been running fine on this instance for months, and suddenly started crashing today. Not only that, but it also started crashing on a separate cloned instance that I hadn't touched. Very strange. Perhaps related to whatever update was recently pushed for this AMI?

On first attempt at invoking '$ google-chrome-stable' I get the following error:

```
[1917:1917:0213/165941.946941:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1512)] Unable to open X display.
```

On later attempts I get a segmentation fault.

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/opt/google/chrome/chrome    '.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f7c532462dd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
```

Any ideas how to investigate what's going on with google-chrome-stable? Perhaps I could try to rollback the AMI to a previous version, or just start up a new instance. I strongly believe it was the AMI upgrade since Selenium/google-chrome-stable was running just fine this morning before the update. And the update broke two separate EC2 instances, one of which hadn't been touched today.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround just by using the pip3 module "pyvirtualdisplay" which is a wrapper for X. I still don't know what caused Xvfb to break, but if you find this question with the same problem try using that module.